# "Sign-in with facebook" code in Sencha ! to integrate in apps

Tags: extjs

I am creating an app using Sencha and I need to integrate the facebook login in it . When i click on the "login in with facebook " button , if the user is not logged in facebook ,it should show a pop-up to enter facebook email-id and password, else if the user has already logged in it should just sign-in with facebook authentication. How do I implement this using sencha touch . Please help . It would be helpful if the code for this functionality is provided.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you have to create JavaScript SDK app with facebook ([please follow this link](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)). After the app is created you will have APP ID. Then add the following code to app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'FBLogin',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            items:[
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    html: '<center><div id="fblogin" class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div></center>'
                }
            ],
            listeners:{
                render: function(obj, eOpts){
                    window.fbAsyncInit = Ext.bind(this.onFacebookInit, this);
                    (function(d){
                        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
                    }(document));
                }
            },
            onFacebookInit: function(){
                console.log('onFacebookInit');
                var me = this;
                FB.init({
                    appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
                    status     : true,
                    xfbml      : true
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', Ext.bind(me.onFacebookAuthResponseChange, me));
            },
            onFacebookAuthResponseChange: function(response){
                this.down('panel').setVisible(false);
                alert("Success fully Logged in");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

There will be a field called 'SiteURL:' under Website with facebook Login when you create Facebook APP. That should be pointed to your web app URL. (ex: http://example.com)

Comment: Nice, but this opens a popup window, any idea how to open a modal window within the app?

Comment: Although it works in Chrome. This method doesn't work on native android Sencha APP

Answer (score 4):

You could try using [Phonegap Facebook Connect Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) 0.4.0 (stable version) 
and Use [Phonegap Plugin Build](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/#googtrans%28en%29) to build package for Android,Iphone ,windows phone,blackbery,etc.

```
//on Device Ready
    FB.init({ appId: "appid", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });
   // call for native app if there else give a popup for login
    FB.login(
                             function(response) {
                             if (response.session) {
                             alert('logged in');
                             } else {
                             alert('not logged in');
                             }
                             },
                             { scope: "email" }
                             );
```

Inorder to integrate with sencha which needs to add three script files cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js, phonegap.js and facebook-js-sdk.js in index.html file and add config.xml file to project build for phone gap build for building native app(without using the sencha native packaging).For config.xml file configuration please see this [config Help](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics) 
If any doubt please see github example  [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/example/Simple/index.html)
Hope it works